# Imprimir un arreglo en C, con apuntadores

Tags: c++, array

Tengo este código en C++, pido llenar un arreglo en una un función `getValores` esta regresa el apuntador al primer valor del array y se guarda dentro de `*llaves`, para corroborar la información que esta dentro mando el tamaño del arreglo `nLlaves` y el apuntador que representa el arreglo, a la función `imprimir` está no imprime correctamente el array, alguna alma piadosa que me un norte del porqué. :(

Entrada:

El primera linea es la cantidad de elementos, y la segunda linea los elementos que contendrá el arreglo

```
6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Salida:

```
Direccion: 0x7ffee3dd6940  Valor: 2076442879 
Direccion: 0x7ffee3dd6944  Valor: 1839269441 
Direccion: 0x7ffee3dd6948  Valor: 0 
Direccion: 0x7ffee3dd694c  Valor: 0 
Direccion: 0x7ffee3dd6950  Valor: 24 
Direccion: 0x7ffee3dd6954  Valor: 48
```

Codigo:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


/* Declaración de las funciones */
int *getValores(int tam);
void imprimir(int tam, int *arreglo);


int main() { 
    int nLlaves;

    cin >> nLlaves;
    int *llaves = getValores(nLlaves);
    imprimir(nLlaves, llaves);
    
    return 0;
}

int *getValores(int size)
{
    int valores[size];  
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++)
        cin >> valores[i]; 

    return valores;
}

void imprimir(int size, int * lista)
{
    printf("imprimir(): \n");
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) 
        printf("Direccion: %p  Valor: %d \n", (lista + i), *(lista + i));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En esta línea:

```
int valores[size];
```

Creas una variable [**con almacenamiento automático**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_class_specifiers). Dicha variable se elimina al salir de su ámbito (al llegar al `return` de la función, en tu caso). A partir de ese momento, el espacio ocupado pasa a estar *disponible* para el sistema, que lo reutilizará para otras cosas.

En otras palabras: el sistema *machacará* tus datos en cualquier momento posterior a ejecutar al `return`.

Para evitar esto, has de utilizar variables con almacenamiento dinámico:

```
int *getValores( int size ) {
    int *valores = new int[size];

    for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        cin >> valores[i];

    return valores;
}
```

Saliendo un poco del tema principal, si se utiliza memoria dinámica, debería liberarse llamando a `delete` en cuanto deje de ser necesaria. En tu caso, al finalizar el `main( )`:

```
int main( ) { 
    int nLlaves;

    cin >> nLlaves;
    int *llaves = getValores( nLlaves );
    imprimir( nLlaves, llaves );
 
    delete[] llaves; // <- AQUÍ LIBERAMOS LA MEMORIA.
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Woow muchas gracias! Excelente explicación me sirvió bastante!!